Why is friction required to rotate a non-ideal pulley-string system?
As the title says, why does a pulley require friction to rotate?
I understand that, due to the mass of the pulley, the string will have different tensions on either side. [Assuming there are blocks of different masses attached to the system?]
But don't these tensions cause the pulley to rotate? So, where does friction come into play?

this question really needs a figure.

Friction between the rope and the pulley results in a torque, causing the pulley to start rotating from rest. Without friction, there is no torque, and no rotation - in this scenario, the rope simply slides around the frictionless, non-rotating pulley.
If there is no friction, what else could cause the pulley to rotate? A rope is not attached to a pulley in any way.

OH! So, to attach the string to the pulley, friction is necessary, such a basic point! How could I miss it! Thank you very much for that last line.

@AnirudhReddyM It could be easy to misread the freebody diagram of a pulley as suggesting the usual tension vectors are "attached" to the radius of the pulley. Oftentimes in other cases, forces are indeed applied at a fixed point that moves with the object (like the engine of a rocket), but that's not the case with a pulley.

Without friction, the rope would simply slide over the roll with no rotating motion.
